# UserControl Dependency property does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have my UserControl. I want to set Dependency property, but i can not.

**TextBoxExtended.cs**

```
public partial class TextBoxExtended : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MyTextPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyTextProperty", typeof(string), typeof(TextBoxExtended), new UIPropertyMetadata(String.Empty));

        public string MyTextProperty
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(MyTextPropertyProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MyTextPropertyProperty, value); }
        }
```

**TextBoxExtended.xaml**

```
<TextBox x:Name="tbMain" Text="{Binding MyTextProperty}"
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<local:TextBoxExtended x:Name="TextBoxSearch" Height="30" Margin="83,38,193,285" MyTextProperty="MyTextProperty"/>
```

I need to event textchange, i use this code

```
<local:TextBoxExtended x:Name="TextBoxSearch" Height="30" Margin="83,38,193,285" MyTextProperty="{Binding MyText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

but I need to make the changes occurred after the introduction of each character

Comment: Right now you have no source for your textbox control, that is why this is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to set a source object of the Binding in TextBoxExtended.xaml, e.g.

```
<TextBox x:Name="tbMain"
    Text="{Binding MyTextProperty,
                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Use ElementName in Binding of TextBox.

```html
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding MyText, ElementName=TextBoxSearch}" ></TextBox>
            <local:TextBoxExtended x:Name="TextBoxSearch" Height="30"
                                   MyText="Hello World!!!" />
        </StackPanel>
```